# Check connection to local Server:Port with waiting time

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to make a function to test the connection to server:port, it will try connecting to that server:port each 100ms and return **TRUE** if connection is success either return **FALSE** until the time limit is reached.
I have a function as bellow:

```
private static bool _TryPing(string strIpAddress, int intPort, int nTimeoutMsec)
        {
            Socket socket = null;
            try
            {
                socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, false);  
                IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect(strIpAddress, intPort, null, null);
                bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(nTimeoutMsec, true);

                return socket.Connected;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (null != socket)
                    socket.Close();
            }
        }
```

The problem is i'm using another software to make that local Server:Port, and it will take random 10-20sec to complete setting a new port. But the function above will check at the app starts so it will return false immediately without waiting time because the **port** is not opened yet.

```cs
_TryPing("127.0.0.1", 1080, 20000) //Return FALSE
```

Could anyone help me to fix this code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, i don't know why but i need to devide WaitTime by 3 to make this function run properly...

```cs
private static bool TryConnect(string IP, int Port, int WaitTime)
        {
            int RunEvery = 500;
            for (int i = 0; i <= WaitTime/3; i += RunEvery)
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(IP, Port);
                    Console.WriteLine(IP + ":" + Port + " is active");
                    return true;
                }
                catch(SocketException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection could not be established due to: \n" + e.Message);                    
                    Thread.Sleep(RunEvery);
                }
                finally
                {
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I would change the `for` loop into a `while` loop and keep looping until a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) says the `WaitTime` has elapsed. Also, you can't use a timeout with `TcpClient.Connect()`. `TcpClient.BeginConnect()` would allow the connect to be canceled if the loop times out before the connect finishes

Answer (score 2):

If the port is not open then the connect will fail immediately. If you want to wait for a period of time to see if the port ever opens, you need to retry the connect in a loop until it is successful or the timeout has elapsed, eg:

```cs
private static bool hasElapsed(ref Stopwatch sw, int total)
{
    return (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > (long) total);
}

private static bool hasElapsed(ref Stopwatch sw, int total, out int remaining)
{
    remaining = (int) (((long) total) - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    return (remaining < 0);
}

private static bool _TryPing(string strIpAddress, int intPort, int nTimeoutMsec)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    do
    {
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient())
            {
                tcp.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
                IAsyncResult ar = tcp.BeginConnect(strIpAddress, intPort, null, null);
                WaitHandle wh = ar.AsyncWaitHandle;
                try
                {
                    int remaining;
                    if (!hasElapsed(ref sw, nTimeoutMsec, out remaining))
                    {
                        if (wh.WaitOne(remaining))
                        {
                            tcp.EndConnect(ar);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    tcp.Close(); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    wh.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    while (!hasElapsed(sw, nTimeoutMsec));
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a more modern approach that uses a `TaskCompletionSource`.
This allows for proper cancellation, plus you can just await it in async code:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class TcpUtil
{
    public static Task WaitForConnection(string address, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        WaitForConnection(address, port, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), TimeSpan.Zero, cancellationToken);

    public static async Task<Task> WaitForConnection(
        string address, int port,
        TimeSpan connectionTimeout,
        TimeSpan retryPause,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await WaitForConnectionAsync(address, port, connectionTimeout, retryPause, cancellationToken);
    }

    private static async Task<Task> WaitForConnectionAsync(
        string address, int port,
        TimeSpan connectionTimeout,
        TimeSpan retryPause,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource(cancellationToken);

        while (!completionSource.Task.IsCompleted && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                using var tcpClient = new TcpClient
                {
                    SendTimeout = connectionTimeout.Milliseconds,
                    ReceiveTimeout = connectionTimeout.Milliseconds,
                    LingerState = new LingerOption(false, 0)
                };
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(address, port, cancellationToken);
                if (!tcpClient.Connected) continue;

                completionSource.SetResult();
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                await Task.Delay(retryPause, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        return completionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Returning a Task may look a bit odd. However, this allows this code to connect using `async/await` while still using the `TaskCompletionSource` as a mechanism to indicate that it's done.